# Sinking of Cage with weights on one side

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, buoyancy, fluid-statics, stability

If there is a cage with weights strapped on one side, will it always sink towards the weighted side face down? Will the cage rotate so the center of mass is facing downward?

Comment: A very vague question, sorry. For example, imagine there is an upwelling on warm water on the heavy side, balancing things, what then?

Answer (score 0):

Any submerged structure will sink if the weight of the fluid displaced by the structure is greater than the weight of the structure outside the fluid. That's simply [Archimedes Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedes'_principle).

If the center of buoyancy of the structure is directly above the center of gravity relative to the direction of gravity, and body forces exceed buoyant forces then the structure should sink uniformly in the direction of gravity provided there are no unequal drag forces on the structure.

But if the center of buoyancy is at any other angle relative to the center of gravity there will be a force couple or rather torque tending to *right* the structure such that the center of buoyancy is directly above the center of gravity: the state of static equilibrium.

The rate at which the submerged structure will rotate, and if it will settle with either oscillation or exponentially is determined by the net drag force, so determined by the shape/size of the structure and the viscosity of the fluid.

For simple structures an analytical model can provide a first order approximation of the dynamics, but more complex structures are best determined by experiment on either full or scaled models.

Comment: So the torque will occur when the center of buoyancy is not aligned with the center of mass. So it is possible for the the buoyant forces to align with the cage's downward gravity even with the weight on its side?

Comment: If the cage is rectangular, symmetric, probably not. But you might possibly be able to counterbalance the offset weight with a pontoon and boom, same side the weight is attached.

Comment: Shark cages that are used to protect divers typically have pontoons, but on both sides see picture here: http://blogs.solidworks.com/tech/2015/07/solidworks-part-reviewer-shark-cage-tutorial.html